# JQuery selecting radio button using a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to select a radio button using a variable but, although I can print the selected value the button does not stay selected.

This button is defined in an angular template as follows:

```
<a ng-click="selectNode($event, node)">
    <input type="radio" name="library" style="float:left;" id="id-{{n}}" />
</a>
```

Where id is a GUID so is definitely unique.

Then, because it is the angular click event that is called when a button is selected I call this code in selectNode:

```
context.selectedNodes = [node];
$scope.selectedNode = node.$model.name;
var id = '#id-' + node.$model.id;
//console.log(typeof id);
//console.log(id);
$(id).prop("checked", true);
alert($("[name=library]:checked").val())
```

Which should theoretically check the radio button. However, it checks for a moment (it is checked when I call the alert) and then seems to disappear. I am however able to hardcode in an id and it stays checked.

Comment: get rid of all the jQuery and just bind the input to scope model using `ng-model`

Comment: Okay, are there any examples of this? I'm new to Angular and find it a bit intimidating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend diving more into the tools angular gives you to handle this things simply. If you need to track the value on this input, tie it to a model. If you want to process something once the checkbox has changed, use ng-change and tie it to a function.

```
<input type="radio" name="library" style="float:left;" ng-model=libraryModel ng-change="doSomething()" />
```

Keep in mind that doSomething() needs to be in scope, so in your controller, you need to define the function as $scope.doSomething(). Your model will also be attached to the $scope object, so you'd reference it as $scope.libraryModel. You can initialize the model as true or false as needed for a default value in the controller, then any user changes will auto update this value.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing jQuery and Angularjs, and it is not really worth. You can do the following just by using **AngularJS** `ngModel`, if you use AngularJs in your project.

**Controller**

```
function Controller($scope) {

  //Init data input to value 1
  $scope.data = ['1'];

}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="name" value="1" ng-model="data">
<input type="radio" name="name" value="2" ng-model="data">
```

Here, our `$scope.data` is set to **1** in our Controller, so it will match with the first input.